# Remedies to CNN-LSTM overfitting on relatively small image dataset

Tags: lstm, cnn, overfitting

**Notes**

*Using a pretrained model, trying data augmentation (not possible knowing nature of images, lowering number of parameters in the network, all didn't help)*

**Context**

I have a sequence of images. Target is a multivariate continuous time series. I am trying LSTM on CNN without using a pretrained model. Training a CNN model didn't got me a satisfying results. A very sure reason is that train is only on one year. While predicting with test images present is on several months.

Any image augmentation is nearly impossible from nature of images, satellite images on a fixed geo-location, tracking passing clouds.

Along with images, I have time features, and trend, seasonality of target which is known for test set, as it can be scientifically calculated (it's about GHI, estimated by the Ineichen and Perez model).

**Problem**

The problem is with over-fitting, tracking best model on validation set is done by early stopping.

Validation set is a small fraction from train, .9 for train, so train set is furthermore made fewer.

Train is a set of 8804 images, and target variable. Timed Model layers take series of 31 sequences. For example train takes (255,31) and validation takes (29,31).

The model, I came up with is the following:

```
losses_weights=[[1, .4]];
main_input__ = Input(shape=(31, 120, 120, 1), name='main_input__')extraction

x__ = TimeDistributed(
    Conv2D(8, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1)  , activation='relu')
)(main_input__)
x__ = TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))(x__)
x__ = (TimeDistributed(BatchNormalization()))(x__)
x__ = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(8, (2,2), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))(x__)
x__ = TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))(x__)

# extract features and dropout 
x__ = TimeDistributed(Flatten())(x__)
x__ = (TimeDistributed(Dense(8, activation='relu')))(x__)
x__ = Bidirectional(LSTM(lstm, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.3))(x__)
lstm_out__ = Bidirectional(LSTM(lstm, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.3))(x__)
auxiliary_output__ = Dense(8, name='aux_output')(lstm_out__)

auxiliary_input__ = Input(shape=(31, 10), name='aux_input')
z__ = keras.layers.concatenate([lstm_out__, auxiliary_input__])

# We stack a deep densely-connected network on top
# z__ = (LSTM(lstm, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.4))(z__)
z__ = Bidirectional(LSTM(lstm, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.3))(z__)
main_output__ = Dense(8, name='main_output')(z__)
################################################################################

loss=[loss_mse_warmup, loss_mse_warmup];
 #;
model__ = Model(inputs=[main_input__, auxiliary_input__], outputs=[main_output__, auxiliary_output__])
model__.compile(loss=loss_mse_warmup, optimizer='adam', loss_weights=loss_weights)

history__ = model__.fit(x=[x_train, aux_train],y=[y_train, y_train], epochs=100, batch_size=2, validation_split=.9, callbacks=callbacks)
```

loss_mse_warmup is just a mean_squared_error that ignores 5 first training input signals.

**Tries**

1. Several Batch-size lengths: [32, 16, 8, 2].
2. loss weights ranging in [[1, .4], [1, .3], [1, .2]].
3. Different variants of number of nodes in CNN: [8,16,32].
4. variants of strides: (2, 2), (1, 1), (3, 3).
5. LSTM layer number of nodes: 20 seems to be far better from other
   tries.
6. Stacking two layers of LSTM gives nearly same result as one layer for main input and auxiliary input.
7. Validation and train loss of auxiliary output is less than main output, so auxiliary data is useful.
8. Time sequences tried: 62, 31 and 1. 31 Is slightly better. it represents half a day.
9. Tested pretrained mobilenet model wrapped in TimeDistributed layer. But it didn't show better results.

*All tries didn't achieve validation loss better than .2 knowing that learning can be improved, knowing the challenge platform.*

This is a visualization of the model:

[image]